# Delay load of iframe with javascript or jquery?

Tags: jquery, iframe, loading, delay

i have got a iframe in my website which i m using but when the iframe loads it shows a logo for 1 second in the beginning can i delay the iframe loading time with javascript/jquery so the logo dosent show in the beginning?

Any help would be highly appreciated thanks

Comment: If the logo is from the external site, delaying the loading wont do much good ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout) to put delay

```
setTimeout(function(){
        //your code here.
}, 5000);
```